# HTML5 form validation customize

Tags: javascript, html, contact-form

I've use a HTML5 form for a website. I've used "required" for all the field. As a result, it prevents submit the form as empty. But, it can't handle the proper syntax for all the field. See the [website](http://abidhasan.zxq.net/firm/test_form.html) I've used input type="text", "tel", "number", "date" etc. If anyone give input word at date/number/tel, still it's accept! If anyone don't tick the radio, it's accept too. I thought, if I use HTML5 form, I need not use javascript for validation. But, may be I need now. So, without changing any design/style how can I don't allow submit the form without proper syntax for date, tel, number etc? I've checked everything at firefox. At chrome, everything is same to firefox. Just for input type="date", chrome assure to input proper date.

Necessary HTML Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header class="page_title">
            <h1>Create New Job</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="form">
            <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="#">
                <label>Job ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="job_id" id="job_id" placeholder="1" required />
                <label>Start Date:</label>
                <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" required>
                <label>Deadline:</label>
                <input type="date" name="deadline" id="deadline" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" required>
                <label>Finish Date:</label>
                <input type="date" name="finish_date" id="finish_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" required>
                <label>Budget($):</label>
                <input type="number" name="Budget" id="Budget" placeholder="100" required>
                <label>Client ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="client_id" id="client_id" placeholder="1" required />
                <label>Client Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="01712345891" required />
                <label>Bidder ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="bidder_id" id="bidder_id" placeholder="1" required />
                <label>Number of Supervisor:</label>
                <select title="Supervisor">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                </select>
                <label>Odesk Profile ID:</label>
                <input type="url" name="odesk_id" id="odesk_id" placeholder="https://www.odesk.com/jobs/Frontend-engineer" required>
                <label>Owner Type:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="owner_type" id="owner_type" value="member" /><label class="text_label">Member</label>
                <input type="radio" name="owner_type" id="owner_type" value="employee" /><label class="text_label">Employee</label>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label>Message:</label> 
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="2" cols="20" placeholder="Your enquiry goes here" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </section>
 </div>
```

CSS code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clear { clear: both; }

article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 26px;    
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
.form {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 2px;
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
}
form {
    border: none;
    background: #fff;   
}

.form label { 
    display: block; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    float:left; 
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 15px; 
}
.form label.text_label {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px 20px 15px 10px; 
}
.form input, .form select {
    float:left; 
    font-size:13px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
.form input:required {

}
input:valid {
    border: 1px solid #909090;

}
input[type=text]:invalid, input[type=date]:invalid, input[type=number]:invalid, input[type=email]:invalid, input[type=tel]:invalid, input[type=url]:invalid, textarea:invalid {
    border: 1px solid #909090;

}

.form input[type=text], .form input[type=date], .form input[type=number], .form input[type=email], .form input[type=tel], .form input[type=url] { 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 27px;
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    border-radius: 3px; 
}
.form input[type=file] {
    width: 500px;   
}
.form select {
    width: 500px;
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    border-radius: 3px; 
}
.form input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;  
}
.form textarea { 
    float: left; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 82px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #909090; 
}
.form input[type="submit"] { 
    margin: 10px 0 20px 220px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 30px; 
    background: #FF6D1F; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), 0 1px 0 #9FE662 inset; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form input[type="submit"]:hover { 
    background: #FF822E;
}

input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus, input[type=search]:focus, input[type=date]:focus, input[type=number]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, select:focus, input[type=tel]:focus, input[type=url]:focus {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #595959;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(103, 102, 106, .7);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(103, 102, 106, .7);
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Yep, you are going to need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Back at those days, (at least most) browsers didn't implement HTML5 validation. You can now use the given code and the validation will happen.

Even so, fields like "tel" don't work as expected. Then, I generally use ["pattern"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute), where it validates a RegExp.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="job_id" id="job_id"
    placeholder="1" required pattern="\d+"/>
```

If you want further validation features, I suggest you use [this jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).